# Getting an image from a salesforce url using an apex controller

Tags: apex, static-resources, images

I am trying to get an image located at https://na1.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P24000002sSRUEA2 in an apex controller and it complains about authorization..Below is my code

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); req. req.setEndpoint('https://na1.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P24000002sSRUEA2'); 
req.setMethod('GET');
 Http binding = new Http(); 
HttpResponse res = binding.send(req); 
Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob(); 
System.debug('image' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image));
```

---

i am new to apex.how do i do this right

Comment: Is this the same instance you are working where the image is available? or some other SF instance?

Comment: yes.the image is in the same instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your image is in same org then just query the attachment record and use the body.

```
attachment acc = [select id,body from attachment where id = '00P24000002sSRUEA2' LIMIT 1] //id hardcode is not a good option you have to be double sure that you need this or store this in custom setting
```

then use

```
String strImage = 'data:image/png;base64,'+EncodingUtil.base64Encode(acc.body);
```

but if this is a single image or you need to display it somewhere else then store this in Static Resource, make it public and use the static resource.

```
{!URLFOR($Resource.file,'0.jpg')}
```

Comment: thanks man..this helped.but can you get me some resources on how make it a static public resource since it will be only a single imag..thanks again

Answer (score 0):

What's the error message?

If the image lives in another org to the one you're in, you might be getting hit with a CORS (cross origin resource sharing) error.

Comment: when i try to access the base64 encoded image it redirects me to a salesforce login page.NB image is in the same org. Also this image needs to be shown a android mobile client

Comment: odd. It shouldn't need to re-authenticate. Where does teh image live? Is it an attachement somewhere, a chatter image, in Files, in Documents? I'm wondering if there are some privacy setting on the image file stopping you